# How would I go about efficiently printing every "official" emoji character?

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji

I would like to print every official emoji; "official" meaning codified by the [Unicode consortium](https://unicode.org/). My problem is that I don't really know how to go about it efficiently. As the answer to my question may be applied to any "language" (e.g., HTML, Java, Python, etc.) I will use HTML in my examples.

So, I have something rudimentary now, it looks something like this:

```
var emojiSpan = document.getElementById('emojiSpan');
var emojiID = 126979;
for(var i = 0; i< 2600; i++){
    emojiSpan.innweHTML = '&#' + (emojiID + i) + ';';
}
```

This solution ... works, but not well. [See JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3hcynsem/)

I know that If I want to print "grinning face" I need to use `&#128512;`.

I know that If I want to print the U.S. Flag, I need to use `&#&#127482;&#127480;`, which is 'U' + 'S'.

I know if I want to print "man medium-light skintone", I need to use `&#128104;&#127996;`, which is man + medium-light skin tone.

So, some emojis require zero variants, some require one, and some require two. Maybe more, I don't know.

My specific question, then, is there a way to print all emojis with all variants **efficiently**?

Is there a known pattern of when to start applying which variant to which codepoint(s) out there that I can use?

Will I need a bunch of statements like so?

```
if(at this codepoint){
    // apply this/these variant(s)
} else if(at this codepoint){
    // apply this/these variant)(s)
} ... and so on
```

Comment: What do you mean by "efficiently"?

Comment: @OrangeDog Not using a TON of if/else or switch statements, without having to check where I am in the list of codepoints while iterating over them. That kind of thing. Also, knowing exactly where to start. I kind of felt my way in the dark to start at `126979`.

Comment: I mean, there has to be a way, right? Every cell phone manufacturer has a nice grid for you to pick from when typing emojis. Surely there is some "method to the madness" that is Unicode.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you mean by "all". Are you interested in [every combination of two people kissing](https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts-13.1/emoji-zwj-sequences.html#1f9d1_1f3fc_200d_2764_fe0f_200d_1f48b_200d_1f9d1_1f3fd)? All [52,000 possible skin tone combinations](https://blog.emojipedia.org/why-there-arent-black-family-emojis/) of a multi-person family? Cell phone keyboards decide which emojis they want to include. They don't show "Every possible emoji" because not all of the emojis are supported by every font.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, every combination that exists from the Lithuanian flag to a medium-light skin-tone lesbian family.

Comment: A raw list is useless. Nobody wants to scroll through 50,000 emoji to find "woman with medium skin tone eating a taco with green salsa." You are going to have to organize them, say as "flags", "food", "animals", "sports", "occupations", etc. and then maybe skin tone selection as a secondary option. At this point you are doing curation, not a programmatically generated list.

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm not doing it for other people, I'm doing it for me.

Comment: There is no way to know a priori whether a particular code point is an emoji, and if so, what variant selectors it supports, or what other characters it can combine with. That information is in the Unicode specification. Not all font support all the variants, anyway. And vendors can [create their own custom emoji by means of ZWJs](https://jeremyburge.com/post/129520141524/apple-has-created-an-eye-in-speech-bubble-emoji) without registering them with any entity.

Answer (score 2):

[The Unicode Standard](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/index.html#Emoji_Properties_and_Data_Files) should have everything you need.

For example, the file [emoji-sequences.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.1/emoji-sequences.txt) includes all the official flag sequences, skin tone and gender variations, etc.

As you just want to list all emoji, simply parse and print the contents of all the emoji data files. There are an awful lot.